# tftp client not receiving from server (send to wrong port)

Tags: c++, unix, client, port, tftp

I'm writing my own TFTP-client.
The client is written in c++ (part wise c) and runs on a unix system (Linux Debian stable).

Here is my problem:

I can send my read-request(RRQ) to the TFTP-server(Open TFTP Server on Windows XP). The TFTP-server receives the RRQ, but can't send the answer.

On the server side I see this message: Client 192.168.1.110:55239 C:\OpenTFTPServer\test.txt, Communication Error

But the port 55239 is not the port I defined in my TFTP-Client.

Here are my code-parts:

- set client and server adresses:

  ```
  memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(servport); // servport=69
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.152"); 

  memset(&cliaddr,0,sizeof(cliaddr));
  cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  cliaddr.sin_port = htons(cliport); // cliport=13337
  cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.110");
  ```
- connect & bind:

  ```
  if (connect(serv, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, serv_length) < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to connect with the server!");
  }
  if(bind(cli, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, cli_length)<0)
  {
      bail("Unable to bind to adr & port!");
  }
  ```
- create TFTP request:

  ```
  memset( &cBuf1, 0, sizeof cBuf1);
  rdwrFrame = (struct tftp_wr_rq *)&cBuf1;
  rdwrFrame->opcode=htons(1);
  rdwrFrame->data={'t','e','s','t','.','t','x','t','\0','o','c','t','e','t','\0'};
  ```
- send TFTP request:

  ```
  if (sendto (serv,cBuf1,19,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,serv_length) < 0)
  {
      bail ("Send the first requirment Frame error -- UDP");
  }
  ```

Here is my question:

What am I doing wrong, that the TFTP-Server receives the wrong port? I thought it should be set with cliaddr.sin_port = htons(cliport);

Thanks for your help & regards
Rico

**Answer:**

My problem was, that I combined the wrong sockets with the wrong address structs

Here are my working code-parts:

- create sockets:

  ```
  serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (serv < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to create socket tx!");
  }

  cli = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (cli < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to create socket rx!");
  }
  ```
- set client and server adresses:

  ```
  memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(servport);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.152"); 

  memset(&cliaddr,0,sizeof(cliaddr));
  cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  cliaddr.sin_port = htons(cliport);
  cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.110");
  ```
- connect & bind:

  ```
  if(bind(cli, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, cli_length)<0)
  {
      bail("Unable to bind to adr & port!");
  }

  if (connect(serv, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, serv_length) < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to connect with the server!");
  }
  ```
- create TFTP-Request:

  ```
  memset( &cBuf1, 0, sizeof cBuf1);
  rdwrFrame = (struct tftp_wr_rq *)&cBuf1;
  rdwrFrame->opcode=htons(1);
  rdwrFrame->data={'t','e','s','t','.','t','x','t',(char)0,'o','c','t','e','t',(char)0};
  ```
- send TFTP-Request:

  ```
  if (sendto (cli,cBuf1,19,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,serv_length) < 0)
  {
      bail ("Send the first requirment Frame error -- UDP");
  }
  ```
- receive Data:

  ```
  recvfrom(cli,cBuf2,19,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,(socklen_t*)&cli_length);
  ```

Comment: Hi Rico, how is the variable cliport defined/set?

Comment: Hi, the cliport is an unsigned short --> unsigned short cliport = 13337

Comment: Have you tried a straightforward check of `cliaddr.sin_port = 13337` by any chance?

Comment: I tried that: `cliaddr.sin_port=13337;` and that: `cliaddr.sin_port=htons(13337);` but i still see a random port when looking at the server

Comment: also should be able to specify 
`sendto (serv,cBuf1,19,0,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,serv_length)`  but for the receive it should be in the format of
`connect(intValHere,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)`  I think the connect format may be the issue.

Think you were just missing sizeof in the connect.

Whichever way, late me know and I can exapnd or give a more detailed answer.

Comment: To your comment: the serv_length is the value of `sizeof(serv_addr)` - OK, i figured out how to send the package with the right source port. I make the fault to create 2 sockets, a rx and a tx socket (cli and serv) then i bind on the cli socket and connect on the serv socket. this way, the message was send without a definded port and took a random number. The problem now is, I still don't receive an answer in my client, and still get the communication error because of a unreachable port

Comment: Are you trying to make  aclient that can both send and receive then?

Comment: Yes the client have to send and receive. Because of the way TFTP works. The client sends a Read-Request and receives a Data-Package, then he send a Ack-Package and receive the next Data-Package an so on...

Comment: OK, so have you set clientRcvPort and clientSendPort as well as servRcvPort and servSendPort?  on the client you would have 
`clientRcvPort = mychoice
clientSendPort = servRcvPort`
on the server
`servRcvPort = clientSendPort
servSendPort = clientRcvPort`
Not actual code, merely for illustration, if those ports arent matched up in that order then you can end up with things seeming broken

Comment: I found the problem. It was also a problem of the wrong socket / address combination. I will add my complete solution to my question, because i can't answer it by my self until in 5 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the answer separatly, so nobody has to search it in the original post.

**Answer:**

My problem was, that I combined the wrong sockets with the wrong address structs

Here are my working code-parts:

- create sockets:

  ```
  serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (serv < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to create socket tx!");
  }

  cli = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (cli < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to create socket rx!");
  }
  ```
- set client and server adresses:

  ```
  memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(servport);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.152"); 

  memset(&cliaddr,0,sizeof(cliaddr));
  cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  cliaddr.sin_port = htons(cliport);
  cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.110");
  ```
- connect & bind:

  ```
  if(bind(cli, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, cli_length)<0)
  {
      bail("Unable to bind to adr & port!");
  }

  if (connect(serv, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, serv_length) < 0)
  {
      bail("Unable to connect with the server!");
  }
  ```
- create TFTP-Request:

  ```
  memset( &cBuf1, 0, sizeof cBuf1);
  rdwrFrame = (struct tftp_wr_rq *)&cBuf1;
  rdwrFrame->opcode=htons(1);
  rdwrFrame->data={'t','e','s','t','.','t','x','t',(char)0,'o','c','t','e','t',(char)0};
  ```
- send TFTP-Request:

  ```
  if (sendto (cli,cBuf1,19,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,serv_length) < 0)
  {
      bail ("Send the first requirment Frame error -- UDP");
  }
  ```
- receive Data:

  ```
  recvfrom(cli,cBuf2,19,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,(socklen_t*)&cli_length);
  ```